# RabbitMQ exchange/queue design - one or several messages

Tags: service, routes, rabbitmq, message

I try to route messages to differnt queues but i cant get my head around the problem (maybe a simple one) if my applications should send several messages or just one.

For example i want to start a job which emits 1 message and it gets delivered in the right queue. The consumer (worker) does his work and when finished sends the response which should do several things (eg. db update, send mail ...): BUT HOW?

1.) bind queues with the routingkey for example: job.done.* to queue db-update, send-mail where the consumer does the db update and mail send?

2.) create an db exchange with queue bindings to db-update and create aswell an send-mail exchange with queue send-mail and at the worker create one message for each exchange?

So they main question is more or less, if the message should trigger more then 1 action (delivered to more then 1 queue) would it be feasible to create 1 exchange for each service and send several messages or rely only on routingkeys?

My feeling tells me i should rely on the routingkey and bind queues but if the architecture get more complex only a few topic exchanges seems a bit wrong as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use exchange with fanout type. A fanout exchange routes messages to all of the queues that are bound to it.

Comment: Thats right. But what if job1 should send a mail and db update on complete and job2   send a mail, db update and write a file to s3? With this approach i would have for every "logic" in my app 1 exchange ... is this a good way to go?

And what would be the difference and/or benefit to just bind to a topic exchange with routing keys?

Comment: The both jobs do their tasks for every message independently? Who produce the messages?